# Trying to redirect with and without trailing slash

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

I have moved a blog to a subdomain and on the subdomain all the categories have changed so I want to do a list of 301 re-directs from old domain to subdomain (different hosting).

The problem I am having is adding on the trailing slash so I don't have to list every URL twice.

I tried this in `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$1/ [L,R=301] 

Redirect 301 /blog/test/ https://new.domain.com/test/
Redirect 301 /blog/example/ https://new.domain.com/example/
(etc...)
```

This doesn't work though as the browser detects too many re-directs.

What is the proper syntax here?

I also tried:

```
RedirectMatch /blog/test/?$ https://new.domain.com/test/ [L,R=301]
```

But that doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: "the browser detects too many re-directs." - You should be getting this error if the target is "different hosting"? But it looks like you might have been mixing mod_rewrite and mod_alias redirects - this is not recommended. `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are mod_alias, not mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Please use bellow syntax

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` makes shure that files that are existing will not get a slash added.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php` exludes a sample url that shouldn’t be rewritten.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ finally fires when a urls doesn’t contain a trailing slash – this is all what we want. Now we need to redirect these url with the trailing slash:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]` does the 301 redirect to the url with the trailing slash appended for us. You should replace domain.com with your url.

Comment: you might want to add a bit of explanation why this syntax will work

Comment: Added description

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that seems to work is:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/test/?$ https://new.domain.com/test/
```

Comment: Note that this only redirects that one specific URL (unlike the `Redirect` directive you had initially). For instance, this won't redirect `/blog/test/something`, if that is a concern?